# How To Grab The Corresponding Rank Of any Reddit Post

Tags: rank, reddit

I have been getting set of reddit data by using a php script. It contains the title, no of upvotes, no of comments and the url of the perticular article. But i also want to grab the current **Reddit RANK** of that article as well.

[image]

Can anyone let me know a way to get the reddit rank of any reddit post?

Comment: any expert??...

Comment: Which rank?  Perhaps how far down it is in the `hot` listing for its containing subreddit?

Comment: exactly yes "how far down it is in the hot listing for its containing subreddit".. do you know anyway to find this out

Answer (score 2):

Reddit posts don't have any statically-defined rank number; that is, there's no value in the database associated with a post that says "this post is #3 in its subreddit, sorted by hot".  What *is* stored is a ["hot" value](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx#L47-L58), which can be used to sort a bunch of posts into an ordered list.

As a result, you won't find the information you're looking for in the detail view of a post; you have to construct it yourself.  You don't have any of your code here, but in psuedocode it'd be something like this:

```
i = 1
for post in get_posts('r/redditdev'):
    store(post, i)
    i++
```